# Golang proxy Getting RequestURI from request

Tags: go, proxy

I am trying to build a proxy server referring [medium](https://medium.com/@mlowicki/http-s-proxy-in-golang-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code-6a51c2f2c38c) post. I am not able to log the RequestURI

```
func handleTunneling(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("SCHEME:", r.URL.Scheme, "HOST:", r.Host, "PATH", r.URL.Path, )
    dest_conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", r.Host, 10*time.Second)
}
```

Result is for https://example.com/custom_page

> SCHEME:  HOST: example.com:443 PATH

But from the  DialTimeout getting the response original uri. Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here, have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from the medium article you've mention, the *handleTunneling* actually still the origin of the request. The main process of proxy-ing actually lying the the *go transfer()* section.

```
go transfer(dest_conn, client_conn)
go transfer(client_conn, dest_conn)
```

which actually in the last block of the *handleTunneling* function.
Thus, it is make sense when you do:

```
fmt.Println("SCHEME:", r.URL.Scheme, "HOST:", r.Host, "PATH", r.URL.Path)
```

at the first line of the function, it is still the original path.